# Unable to set integer constraint in Solver using VBA

Tags: vba, integer, constraints, solver

There seem to be quite a few unsolved issues like this one floating around. I have made sure that none of the replies/answers presented in the other questions solve my problem.

**Goal**:
To set up and activate **Solver using VBA**.

**Problem**:
Everything seems to work except that the **integer constraint is not considered**. This can be confirmed by looking at the Solver dialog box manually after running the VBA.

My code looks like this:

```
SolverReset    

'Set constraints    

SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$L$2:$L$99"), relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"     

SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$N$1"), relation:=2, FormulaText:=0     

SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$N$2:$N$99"), relation:=3, FormulaText:=0    

'Set Objective    

SolverOk SetCell:="$T$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0",_
    ByChange:="$L$2:$L$99", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"    

'Run Solver    

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
```

Opening the solver dialogue box shows that everything except the integer constraint was successfully set up:
[missing integer constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9upN.png)

Please note, that I have already tried:

-excluding 
`FormulaText:="integer"`

-double quotes around my `FormulaText` values

-resetting my computer

Answer (score 0):

Whoo Hoooo!

I somehow stumbled across my answer! Or at least an answer (I still have no idea why the original code doesn't work).

Replacing
`SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$L$2:$L$99"), relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"`

With `SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$2:$L$99", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"`

Seems to have done the trick.

I am still using

`SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("N1"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=0`

and

`SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$N$2:$N$40"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=0`

Because they work... So why change them.

***If anybody can explain why the original code doesn't work I would be really grateful!***